# how to find common variable pairs in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 2 columns, ID and a category name:

```
     X1     X2
    1234   Metal
    1234   Metal
    1234   Plastic
    1234   Plastic
    1234   Glass
    1235   Metal
    1235   Metal
    1235   Plastic
    1235   Plastic
    1235   Glass
    1236   Glass
    1236   Glass
    1236   Metal
    1236   Metal
    1236   Plastic
```

I want to find the most frequent combinations and the count of those combinations of 2 (I will want combinations of 3 or 4 for a larger dataset) across the entire dataset:

```
    Metal, Plastic     2
    Glass, Metal       1
```

I tried to first generate all possible combinations of `X2` by ID (`X1`), so I could then use `dplyr` to aggregate and subset the top combinations. Unfortunately, my dataset is too large for this to run efficiently. Any ideas on an easier and faster way to figure this out?

Comment: Have you used `filter(n_distinct())`?

Comment: OP:  Your question says that you have a solution that's not efficient. Please let us see, as that will be needed to benchmark and because a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) example is required per the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) tag description. You can use `dput()`, `reprex::reprex()` or built-in data sets for reproducible data rather than just showing it for manual transcription by each potential answerer.

Comment: Can a category have a 'combination' with itself? E.g.,  ID `1236` has 3 `Glass` values - would `Glass, Glass` be considered a combination?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at what I think you're getting at. You can change the `top_n` argument and I let categories combine with themselves, but you can just add an additional filter if that shouldn't be the case.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  inner_join(., ., by = c('X1' = 'X1')) %>%
  filter(ID.x != ID.y) %>% # shouldn't count as combo with itself
  group_by(X2.x, X2.y) %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  top_n(5, n) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  X2.x    X2.y        n
  <chr>   <chr>   <int>
1 Metal   Plastic    10
2 Plastic Metal      10
3 Glass   Metal       8
4 Metal   Glass       8
5 Glass   Plastic     6
6 Metal   Metal       6
7 Plastic Glass       6

# Tie results in more than 5 rows for top_n()
```

### Data

```
df <- data.table::fread("X1     X2
1234   Metal
1234   Metal
1234   Plastic
1234   Plastic
1234   Glass
1235   Metal
1235   Metal
1235   Plastic
1235   Plastic
1235   Glass
1236   Glass
1236   Glass
1236   Metal
1236   Metal
1236   Plastic")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
df
#      X1      X2
# 1  1234   Metal
# 2  1234   Metal
# 3  1234 Plastic
# 4  1234 Plastic
# 5  1234   Glass
# 6  1235   Metal
# 7  1235   Metal
# 8  1235 Plastic
# 9  1235 Plastic
# 10 1235   Glass
# 11 1236   Glass
# 12 1236   Glass
# 13 1236   Metal
# 14 1236   Metal
# 15 1236 Plastic
```

---

**For each unique `X1` variable, the count of `X2` elements**

```
 result <- table(cbind.data.frame(df$X1, df$X2))
 result
 #       df$X2
 # df$X1  Glass Metal Plastic
 #   1234     1     2       2
 #   1235     1     2       2
 #   1236     2     2       1
```

**Printing the top two most frequent elements of `X2` for each unique `X1`**

```
 final <- apply(result,1, function(x) names(which(x == max(x))))
 final
 #  df$X1
 #    1234      1235      1236   
 # [1,] "Metal"   "Metal"   "Glass"
 # [2,] "Plastic" "Plastic" "Metal"
```